# Are all functions in the entry script for node js?

Tags: node.js, npm

The code I am looking at is quite simple. It requires a library and uses one of the functions:

```
const bitcoin = require('bcashjs-lib');
.
.
.
const hdPath = bitcoin.hdPath(keychain);
```

Here's an example of it in use elsewhere:

https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS/blob/30f7b0850e65a0cec91ad911e76a935e07c363a5/src/v2/coins/bch.js#L40

Here's the version they're using:

https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS/blob/30f7b0850e65a0cec91ad911e76a935e07c363a5/package.json#L74

However, when I do the same on my own script the function is not defined. And sure enough, the library doesn't have it in the entry file:

https://github.com/BitGo/bcashjs-lib/blob/master/src/index.js

Any tips would be great.

Comment: I don't know bitcoin, but it may simply be you don't have the same version of "bcashjs-lib"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BitGo` module is able to use `hdPath()` because they define it themselves and attach it to the bitcoin object. It's not part of `bcashjs-lib`.

See [here where they define it](https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS/blob/54b3474dbc50dcaffd6848b3fef84580de30fd61/src/bitcoinCash.js):  (line 129)

```
bitcoin.hdPath = function(rootKey) {
   const cache = {};
   //etc...
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Would you know how that object is passed to the other file?

Comment: it's by the ways "require" work.
when you require a module, you get the exact object each time, even if the require call are made in different file. so if you modify a module, the modification will be available everywhere else. not recommended if you don't know what you are doing, cause you could create a real mess with other module requiring the same module in your project.

Comment: It looks like they are monkey patching `bcashjs-lib` -- they are adding a function to the object exported by the module. After that any module that imports it will have access to the new function.

Comment: Great. Thanks so much guys.